# Iterators on temporary container object

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have a function which returns a STL container by value, say std::list

```
std::list<Foo> get_Foolist()
{
    std::list<Foo> lst;
    //populate lst
    return lst;
}
```

or

```
class SomeClass
{
    std::list<Foo> get_Foolist()
    {
        return m_foolst;
    }
    ...
    private:
    std::list<Foo> m_foolst;
};
```

Now, I have a snippet of code which uses this function to get the list and iterate on it in following way,

```
std::list<Foo>::iterator i = get_Foolist().begin();
//use i like ... cout << *i << endl;
```

When I saw this code, I felt it should not work since we are using iterator on a temporary object which will get deleted after expression is executed. But, to my surprise it was working.

This works with STLPort5.2 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Later, when we removed STLPort and started using STL implementation provided with compiler we started facing crashes at the point.

It is revealed that code above doesn't work with VS 2008 list implementation but it works with the STLPort.

I tried to run it on various other compilers and results were as follows,

- Visual Studio 2008 (Without STLport5.2) - Crashes
- Visual Studio 2008 (With STLPort5.2) - Works
- Visual Studio 2013 (Without STLport5.2) - Crashes
- GCC 4.3.6 (Without STLPort5.2) - Works
- Clang 3.0 (Without STLPort5.2) - Works

(GCC and Clang were used from http://melpon.org/wandbox/)

Now my questions are,

1. Which implementation is correct(as per standard)?
2. Why it succeeds on all implementations other that VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Which implementation is correct(as per standard)?

Presumably all of them.

> 2. Why it succeeds on all implementations other that VS?

It is ***undefined behaviour*** because you are de-referencing invalidated iterators. So it can fail in an infinite number of ways. Or appear to work, which is a just another mode of failure.

Comment: So shall I say that Microsoft's implementation is more trustworthy as it failing in debug build with assertion failure while it crashes in release?

Comment: @harshad It is a matter of opinion. Let's say in this particular instance it was more useful in finding a bug. But I don't know if MS' implementation is designed to catch that bug always or if you just got lucky. In general, you should try to run some static analysis on your code to find this kind of problem.

Comment: @harshad: It's undefined behavior.  The MS compiler is guaranteed to do anything.  In this case you got a segfault, but you may not under different compilation options. It means nothing aside from the fact that your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ there are many philosophical design rules (some of which telling one the opposite of the other) but one that is very often applied is "trust the programmer".

This rule allows the implementers to simply ignore mistakes on the programmer side: when you write code that does something wrong (like deleting an object twice, or iterating over a container that doesn't exist any more) the compiler is free to just ignore what would happen instead of raising a runtime error. This is what is called "undefined behavior".

The rationale is that you will never do that and it's not worth wasting even just a nanosecond at runtime to check for those conditions to happen.

If you get an immediate crash because the OS blocks an access outside your allocated virtual address space you can consider yourself extremely lucky.

If you get a random value that shows crazy result you can still consider yourself lucky... unfortunately what happens sometimes is that you get an "reasonable" result anyway and this will hide the bug for long time because wrong code will do the "correct thing" and thus the programmer will move on to implement other features and adding more code on top of the wrong one.

In other words "undefined behavior" means that anything can happen, including nothing.

Normally what happens is that the code will fail only when the damage is high (i.e. when the code is in production and you are in a hurry with an angry customer).

Comment: "anything can happen, including nothing."  Wonderful synthesis!